# Python Social Auth: specify "realm" and "redirect_to" settings

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

[Python Social Auth](https://github.com/python-social-auth) (In case of Django)

I am trying to connect auth-system with one OpenID provider, and could not find where **return_to** and **realm** settings should be specified, so the final POST to third-party provider will look like:

```
'openid.return_to': 'https://example.com/',
'openid.realm': 'https://another_example.com/'
...
```

Now, even in production it sends 127.0.0.1 for both

Big thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `openid.return_to` depends on nginx/apache host header setting
- `openid.realm` can be defined in global Django setting `OPENID_TRUST_ROOT`

P.S. `openid.return_to` also could be defined by overriding `build_absolute_uri` method in custom *strategy* class (global Django setting `SOCIAL_AUTH_STRATEGY`)